# .net 4.5 thread pool stops creating threads?

Tags: async-await, .net-4.5, threadpool, amazon-sqs

I have this problem in several different Windows services that make extensive use of the async/await paradigm to run a lot of different i/o-intensive tasks.  After a period of running, which can be from 8 hours to several days, some of my tasks stop being serviced (that is, they don't proceed after the i/o completes).  This is not because the thread pool is out of threads, since if I look at the threads in perfmon, there are from 10-20 threads running in the process; instead, it looks as though the thread pool is refusing to create new threads even though there are tasks waiting to be serviced.

In particular, looking at perfmon, when the service starts and is behaving normally the thread count varies as tasks run through the system, going from about 20 to 70 or more at times of high activity and then slowly going down.  When the tasks start hanging, the thread count seems to get stuck in the 18-22 range.

The tasks most affected seem to be tasks that take a while to complete, in particular waiting for messages from an Amazon SQS queue.

I've tried setting the ThreadPool minimum threads to a higher value; this seems to delay the onset of symptoms (although its hard to tell, because the onset is so variable) but not eliminate it.

I'm hoping someone knows enough about the inner workings of the .net 4.5 ThreadPool that they can explain this behavior, or point to something else I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Search for this user: "Stephen Cleary" and look through some of his posts. He has some pretty good posts on this topic.

Comment: `or point to something else I might be doing wrong` The easiest way to find this out is to create a minimal, reproducible example.